# Haskell divide String into Lists

Tags: string, haskell, readfile

I've been working for quite a while on this project and just want to ask if it is possible to divide a string into a set list. At the moment I have

```
type Rate = (String,Int)
type Film  =  (String,String,Int,[Rate])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)]),("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)])...
```

And I have tailored a lot of functions to be able to work with the `[Film]` type.

My problem arose when I tried to import the data from a text file.

Using `readFile` I am only able to read

```
[("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)]),("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)])
```

as

```
"[("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)]),("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)])"
```

and I don't know if there is a way to make the `readFile` read to a different data type rather than string or to convert this string to fit in the datatype.

Any advice would be really appreciated. Sorry if I didn't phrase the question well. In summary, is there a way to make a string into just data to be able to implement into a type or is there a way to `readFile` as something other than `String`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a typo or you're missing a `]` at the end of your file? If so, that's the reason `read` is throwing an incorrect parse. Make sure the string provided to `read` is valid Haskell code.

Comment: no sorry, there is more in the database i just cut it to show part of it. but thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:read):

```
main = do
  string <- readfile "data.txt"
  let testDatabase = read string :: [Film]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, umm but i've tried something similar before and well i get the message \\Prelude.read: no parse//  if i try to view(print) the [film] to see if it has worked

Comment: There may be something wrong with your data. It works for me with your example: `read "[(\"Blade Runner\",\"Ridley Scott\",1982,[(\"Amy\",5), (\"Bill\",8), (\"Ian\",7), (\"Kevin\",9), (\"Emma\",4), (\"Sam\",7), (\"Megan\",4)]),(\"The Fly\",\"David Cronenberg\",1986,[(\"Megan\",4), (\"Fred\",7), (\"Chris\",5), (\"Ian\",0), (\"Amy\",6)])]" :: [Film]`

Comment: You Are a legend, You are right, something must be wrong with my data, i made a separate txt file and tried it with the data and it worked, thank you, i hope you have a great week.